# What is the best way to handle my softwares licenses?

Tags: licensing

By best I mean more time tested, easier to implement and easier for the users to work with. I **do not** want my licensing crap to interfere with their work.

I was thinking of launching a WCF service that check with my license DB if it's a valid license and if it is, send a True.

If the returned response is False, then shut down the program after telling them to fix their license.

Do you think this is a good way to handle it?

Comment: No. What happens when their network connection fails? The only way this would work is if you allow them to keep working when the network is down. Isn't BioWare using that sort of DRM right now? From what I've heard, the game shuts down if it loses its conncetion to the license server, but they require a constant connection.

Comment: True that; so please suggest something time tested. :)

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: *Any* DRM scheme **can** be cracked eventually. Least amount of hassle, in my opinion (as a user), is a licence key that gets entered once, at installation time.

Comment: But how will I program my software to 'know' if the entered license is correct?

Comment: Any DRM scheme can be cracked.  Any DRM scheme has the potential to interfere with your users.  As it gets harder to crack, it gets more burdensome on your legitimate users.  You need to assess your priorities and state them more explicitly for us to help.

Comment: You might also consider the burden on you.  With your suggestion, you will need to keep a license server up and running 24/7, and that isn't a trivial chore.  If a legit user is told to fix their license, they'll be angry.  Moreover, a potential user may be reluctant to buy your software because they aren't confident of your commitment to keeping the server up.  Large companies like Microsoft and Walmart have just dropped validation server systems in the recent past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to develop or find an algorithm that creates sufficiently complex strings for your license keys.

Generate the license key based on some bit of information unique to a user, like their E-Mail address.

Your program would then require the user to enter their E-Mail address and license key.  It would then ensure the license key is correct by running the same algorithm you did to generate it in the first place.

Comment: Which can cause problems when email addresses change, or when somebody else takes over the application, or when somebody's email address gets distributed as a key.  I was once using some very nice software when it stopped working, because our systems guys had changed our IP addresses.  Fortunately, the customer service was good, and I was up and running again within an hour.  Of course, not all software can be left disabled for an hour without serious consequences.

Comment: I should have stated that the license key should only be required one time.

This scheme is very common, but hardly the "best".  As stated earlier, by FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, any form of DRM can be worked around, you should focus on DRM that will work well enough to discourage the majority of people from using your software illegally, yet be easy enough to deal with that your paying customers don't find it obtrusive.

Comment: Include the algorithm within your program and you have just given it to the crackers.

Comment: Acknowledged, although again, simple protection will keep the majority of people operating legally.  Even companies such as Microsoft and Adobe have issues with cracking, and even Adobe's method of keys + "call home" can easily be defeated by anyone given 5min on google.

Just being a realist on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The approach i have used in the past is a simple one but effective. I generate about a 1000 keys to my software and run them through a hashing algorithm. I then include them within my program (maybe as an array which takes up little space)

I then give out one unique key of the 1000 generated to each customer and when they enter that into my software it is hashed with the same hashing algorithm and compared against the included hashes. If it compares true you are registered so save it in your config file.

Every so often i update the program by another build number and recreate the keys and hashes included in that build. You just have to keep track of what keys go with what build, but you can control this with a nice database, etc.

Never had any trouble with this system as it can all be fully automated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating license keys strings using the user's name + dob + user-selected-password.

OR

Use the user's h/w serial numbers and give them a license key online post install. I am assuming at this point only one computer per license is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Pinging the web service will not work if a net connection is not available. You should use a combination of pinging and a grace period. If a customer cannot validate/activate the license within 'X' number of days, THEN you declare it as unlicensed.

Try [CryptoLicensing](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) which supports this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [OffByZero Cobalt](https://cobalt.offbyzero.com/) (obligatory disclaimer: it's produced by the company I co-founded).  You're better off buying an existing proven solution than rolling your own.

As we point out in [Developing for Software Protection and Licensing](http://www.offbyzero.com/resources/software_protection_licensing):

> We believe that most companies would
>   be better served by buying a
>   high-quality third-party licensing
>   system. This approach will free your
>   developers to work on core
>   functionality, and will alleviate
>   maintenance and support costs. It also
>   allows you to take advantage of the
>   domain expertise offered by licensing
>   specialists, and avoid releasing
>   software that is easy to crack.